# Need to just pull .exe part of string with batch

Tags: batch-file

Basically, my output is going to read something like:

```
C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe
C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe
C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zG.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Evernote\Evernote\ENScript.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Evernote\Evernote\Evernote.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Evernote\Evernote\EvernoteCleanup.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Evernote\Evernote\EvernoteClipper.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Evernote\Evernote\EvernotePlayer.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Evernote\Evernote\EvernoteThumbnailer.exe
```

What I need is to be able to just strip out the .exe filename so I can run things against it such as Taskkill if need be.

Comment: It is not clear what you need. Can you include an example of what should be the final output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the for command to list all `exe` files in a directory tree.
To show complete path of each file:
`for /R C:\ %%a in (*.exe) Do @echo %%a`
To show filename only:
`for /R C:\ %%a in (*.exe) Do @echo %%~nxa`

Note that this command is recursive and in this example will iterate through all directory tree of drive C.

Comment: Instead of `%%a` use `%%~nxa` to get the `filename.exe` only.

Comment: @foxidrive - By his needed output he wants the name with the full path and not just the file name

Comment: The last line of the question shows that he wants only the filename.

Comment: @foxidrive - Can't argue with that... Added to answer